# Payfort : Charge Amount -> Must be an integer

Tags: c#, validation, payfort

Why payfort(Payment Gateway) only accept integer for Charge or Refund Amount? What in case if I Choose currency->USD and want to receive an amount in decimal (20.50$)

Error :

```
{
"amount": [
"must be an integer"
],
"card": []
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Payfort takes amounts in cents. So if you want $20.50, pass through the value of:

```
2050
```